# How do I get node or process id when using doParallel?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am running a parallel process on a 12 node cluster.

And was wondering if there is a way to get the node-id or node-number or node-name during a `foreach` call?

Something like this:

```
foreach(i = 1:12, .combine=c) %dopar% {node.name()}
```

This will be helpful in processing the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found the following to work:

```
foreach(i = 1:12, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  Sys.getpid()
}
```

This gives a unique process ID for each of the nodes, which can be used as the node id.

Comment: It looks like you really want a worker id, in which case you should include the hostname if you ever plan to run on multiple nodes, since you could have the same process id on different machines, although it isn't likely.

Comment: That's a good idea. My current problem is solved with this solution, however, I will keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for—just so I can filter my log files to look at one worker at a time :)

Answer (score 9):

The foreach package doesn't provide any support for a node id or node name, but R has the "sys.info" function, so you could use:

```
foreach(i = 1:12, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  Sys.info()[['nodename']]
}
```

To create a unique worker id, you can combine the node name with the process id of the worker:

```
foreach(i = 1:12, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  paste(Sys.info()[['nodename']], Sys.getpid(), sep='-')
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as all the nodes are returned with the same name at least on my machine.

Comment: @Shambho If you're running on a 12 node cluster, the hostname should be different on each of the nodes. Is that what you mean by a 12 node cluster, or do you mean that you're creating a cluster object with 12 workers on a single machine? I assumed you were running on a true computer cluster.